# Attach and Share Article Link from Support Service Center" to case option from Articles in Service cloud

Tags: servicecloud, articles

I am unable to see the below "Attach and Share Article Link from Support Service Center" option for few Articles and I can see for few articles. All Articles are  public knowledgebase enabled.

[image: Attach and Share Article Link is visble for few Aricles]

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the following settings for this option to get enable.

[image]

[References](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Knowledge-One-widget-Share-an-article-as-a-URL-Email-an-article-as-a-PDF-unavailable&language=en_US)

Comment: I have already configured the setting I am getting the option for FEW articles. But I observed one thing. I am using Article type="opportunities" , may be is this creating problem? rest of all article types shoing the attach & share link from <site>. Please advice.